# RecyclerView actions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Are there any best practices on using the new RecyclerView animations together with a SQLite database?

In particular, I'm thinking about a pattern that's been around for a while now: sliding a list item off the screen to delete, and giving the user the option to undo.

Like in the Gmail app:
[image]

Comment: Are you resolve this problem?

Comment: No, from what I have ascertained it's pretty hard to do and not worthwhile for me, personally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is hard. My approach to solving this is in two parts, a custom view that shims around the adapter view, and a scroll listener on the recycler view.

The custom view is to handle the sliding item part. The key part is to mark the associated item for deletion when it is put into the slid state. I also like to allow for a second slide to dismiss the undo option.

The scroll listener on the recycler view simply deletes any marked items when onScrollStateChanged is called, you only need to care about changes away from SCROLL_STATE_IDLE. I prefer my deletion to be more lenient than the gmail implementation, so I post a delayed message on the scroll event rather than deleting straight away. You have to remember to cancel it if undo is pressed.

Oh, you also have to do any deletions if the screen is navigated away from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implements SwipeDismiss, use this library

[SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener.java](https://github.com/ammar786-1/MaterialCardsDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ammar/materialcardsdemo/SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener.java)

On dismis you need implements a custom view or use visibility GONE from xml.